# Programatically expand or collapse Telerik grid with detail view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using a Telerik grid with a DetailView. 
I have the grid rendering correctly, but I was wondering if there is a way to collapse/expand all rows programatically using Java Script?

It works if I do it manually one by one, but I would like to offer a master expand/collapse button for all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution here:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/expand-collapse-all-detailviews-in-a-grid.aspx